# Should I hold an Id and the Item

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, class-design, encapsulation, separation-of-concerns

Let's say I have a Customer which contains an Address class like:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }

    // Constructor and other code
}
```

Should I now also have a property for the reference Id to ask another class to give me the `Address`?

```
    public int RefAddressId { get; private set; }

    public Initialize()
    {
        Address = someInterface.GetAdressById(RefAddressId );
    }
```

or should i ask another class to give me the `Address` based on my CustomerId

```
    public Initialize()
    {
        Address = someInterface.GetAdressByCostumerId(Id);
    }
```

Is there a rule why and when I should prefer one over the other?

Or maybe there is even a other more common way to do this.

Comment: It seems superfluous to introduce a separate id, if the client class can get the address directly through a property.

Comment: @JacquesB the property `Address` is `null` at the beginning and will first be filled after calling `Initialize()`. So the question still remains because at that point i could do both of my described variants to set the property

Answer (score 0):

You can follow a suitable practice based on the requirement. In this case, a customer is unique and will have a unique address associated with it. If the address has the possibility of being used by many other customers, then using a separate interface for address seems like a good idea to me. In that case, the object can retrieve the address(possibly a large string) lazily when required, by integrating with the interface. However, if the address is very rarely used by other customers, storing a reference to the Address entity itself works well.